# Cannot connect to Cassandra on localhost

Tags: cassandra

First time using cassandra, I have attempted to configue the yaml file according to other related posts but had no luck so far. Any idea how do so on the localhost?

```
The specified host(s) could not be reached.
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042] Cannot connect), localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
  [localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042] Cannot connect
  [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect
```

Comment: do you have cassandra process running? what's in its console output / logs? what's the content of your .yml file? Please edit your question and add answers for these debugging questions

Comment: Are you on debian and do you have an entry for your hostname in `/etc/hosts` for 127.0.1.1? Remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Inverse the process(s) you already executed. To run `cassandra` on `localhost`, you don't need to change anything so far. You don't need to change `cassandra.yaml`. It'll run by default on localhost. Read the documents carefully.

Learn more about `cassandra.yaml`:https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html

Comment: I have tried with the default config and did not work. I did read the documentation and have followed all steps. I am however very new to this

Comment: If you want to test cassandra, just let me know which version you want to test in your localhost and which operating system you are using, so that I can write another answer for you.

Comment: I have tried primarily the 2.2 version and am using windows

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can stop the Cassandra server and start it again.

```
bin/cassandra -f -R
```

Further this link helps understand 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html

cassandra.yaml config parameters.

You can also make sure that the ports are set correctly native_transport(9042),native_transport_port_ssl(9142),Storage_port(7000),roc_port(9160) and  JMX port(7199).

Lastly,

```
seeds - "127.0.0.1"
```

assuming you are working on single node cassandra setup.

Answer (score 0):

Might be your `DataStax Cassandra Community Server` windows service is stopped. So, start it and reconnect. i hope you get success.

While you are trying to start this service and if it would stopped again then you have to delete the logs folder (where `DataStax` installed) and restart this service.