# Can my docker image connect with a database running on same machine without network configuration?

Tags: docker, cassandra, playframework-2.6

I have created a `docker` image of my web application. I have a `cassandra` database running on my laptop and I am starting the `container` of my web application from the same laptop. The `uri` to connect to database is `localhost:9042`. However, the image is not able to connect with the database. Do I need to do some network configuration for the container to connect to the database?

```
[trace] CassandraRepositoryComponents - database will connect using parameters uri: cassandra://localhost:9042/, cluster name: myCluster
[trace] s.d.c.CassandraConnectionUri - created logger Logger[services.db.cassandra.CassandraConnectionUri]
[trace] s.d.c.CassandraConnectionManagementService - creating session with uri CassandraConnectionUri(cassandra://localhost:9042/) and cluster name myCluster
[trace] s.d.c.CassandraConnectionManagementService - exception in connecting with database com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
Oops, cannot start the server.
```

docker file

```
FROM openjdk:8
RUN mkdir deploy
WORKDIR deploy
COPY target/universal/myapp-1.0.zip .

COPY conf/logback_dev.xml ./logback.xml
COPY conf/application_dev.conf ./application.conf
RUN unzip myapp-1.0.zip
RUN chmod +x myapp-1.0/bin/myapp
EXPOSE 9000
ENTRYPOINT myapp-1.0/bin/myapp -Dplay.http.secret.key=changemeplease -Dlogger.file=/deploy/logback.xml -Dconfig.file=/deploy/application.conf
```

Cassandra is running as a standalone application

Comment: Can you add `Dockerfile` of the app and how you are starting the application? and How casandara is running? Is it container also or stand-alone process on host?

Comment: A wild guess would be to run the application using `docker run --network="host"  IMAGENAME` and other options and should allow the web application to connect to `localhost:9042`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

referring to [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach), I changed the uri string to connect to Cassandra to `cassandra://host.docker.internal:9042/`. And the application is up now!!!

Also, it seems that `host.docker.internal` maps to the ip address of main network interface. When I tried to run `cqlsh` (in another experiment of running `cassandra` as well via `docker` - [Unable to start Cassandra docker image on Win10 Home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62178614/unable-to-start-cassandra-docker-image-on-win10-home)), I noticed this.

```
C:\Users\manuc>cqlsh host.docker.internal 9042
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.1.12': error(10061, "Tried connecting to [('192.168.1.12', 9042)]. Last error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")})
```

Also,
ping host.docker.internal

```
Pinging host.docker.internal [192.168.1.12] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

This domain is configured when `docker` gets installed in `etc/hosts` in `windows`

```
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.1.12 host.docker.internal
192.168.1.12 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your docker container with the `host` network mode which enable that container to use the host network.

```
docker run --network="host" -p 9000:9000 IMAGENAME
```

and then access your application on `http://localhost:9000` and shouldn't see any errors.

1 suggestion for `Dockerfile`, you don't have to `mkdir` if you are specifying the `WORKDIR` as it will create it for you.

```
FROM openjdk:8
WORKDIR deploy
COPY target/universal/myapp-1.0.zip .

COPY conf/logback_dev.xml ./logback.xml
COPY conf/application_dev.conf ./application.conf
RUN unzip myapp-1.0.zip
RUN chmod +x myapp-1.0/bin/myapp
EXPOSE 9000
ENTRYPOINT myapp-1.0/bin/myapp -Dplay.http.secret.key=changemeplease -Dlogger.file=/deploy/logback.xml -Dconfig.file=/deploy/application.conf
```

Comment: sorry. No love. Still getting error `exception in connecting with database com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042] Cannot connect), localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))`

Comment: but `cqlsh` works when I try to connect to `cassandra` from client

Comment: As you can see, it tries to connect `localhost/127.0.0.1:9042`, not sure why both strings are coming?

Comment: looks like this is normal way of printing error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40239278/cannot-connect-to-cassandra-on-localhost

Answer (score 0):

You can not access port opened on the host machine using 127.0.0.1. You need to find the IP assigned to the network interface of your VM (in Mac and Linux you may use `ifconfig` command ). Access the Cassandra using the same IP from your docker container.

Also, check if Cassandra accepts connection from any ip. Setting this to 0.0.0.0 will listen on all network interfaces. Make these changes in the cassandra.yaml config file:

```
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I am on Windows and use Dockers for Windows. No VMs.

Comment: Did you check Cassandra config? Is it configured to listen to all IPs? Also, please find the  IP assigned to docker machine network interface and use the same to connect to Cassandra server.